# Is the inverse of a matrix a division by that matrix?

Tags: matrices

> Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 9 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.
>
> 1. Prove by induction that $A ^n = \begin{pmatrix} 4^n & 0 \\ 3(4^n -1) & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
> 2. Determine whether using the previous formula for $n=-1$ to obtain $A ^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 4^{-1} & 0 \\ 3(4^{-1} -1) & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is valid.

My question concerns (2.): my logic is that as we are dealing with $A ^n$ as a multiplication in part (1.) and by extension in (2.), when $n= -1$ the expression becomes $\dfrac 1 A$ and division is not defined for matrices.

But the book says that when $n= -1$, the answer is the inverse of $A$ and therefore valid. I think, indirectly the scheme assumes that $\dfrac 1 A$ and the inverse of $A$ are one and the same? Is my logic wrong? If so, why?

Please help. Thanks. Mohana

Comment: It seems that your entire question can be summarized as follows: *is it true that $A^{-1}$ means the same thing as $A$ inverse?* If that is your question, then the answer is yes: the $-1$ "matrix power" of $A$ is indeed its inverse.

Comment: It was good of you to provide some amount of context to your question. However, with everything that you've decided to include, your question was excessively long and therefore difficult to read. I hope that in the future, you will try to be a bit more succinct.

Answer (score 2):

For real numbers, the (multiplicative) inverse of a nonzero real number $a$ is the number $a^{-1}$ such that
$$a\cdot a^{-1}=1 .$$

For real numbers, we know that the fraction $1/a$ satisfies this definition, we write
$$a^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$$
in elementary Algebra classes.

You are correct that we do not have division of matrices, so writing $1/\mathbf{A}$ is meaningless for matrices. We write $\mathbf{A^{-1}}$ for the inverse of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

The markscheme is not equating $1/\mathbf{A}$ with $\mathbf{A^{-1}}$.